# Saving an image from a web page to iOS Photos app

Tags: iphone

I have a download image button on a web page. I noticed it requires a number of steps to make the image available in photo app. Steps are:

1. Save the image into a folder.
2. open the image.
3. choose menu "save to photo"
4. Open Photo app and the image will appear there.

Is there any ways to cut the steps here? I wish to have the image appear in Photo app right after I saved the image, something like taking a screenshot?

FYI, I've built the web page with React.js. Android allow the image appears in the Gallery once it is saved.

Thank you.